# Gameboy Advance emulator for Lucid? (No Wine)

Tags: 10.04

Does anybody know of any good GBA emulators for Lucid? I can't run wine on this, so I really need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best GBA emulator for Ubuntu is Mednafen, available in the [Ubuntu Software Centre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mednafen/). It is a muli-system emulator, playing the following:

- Atari Lynx
- Neo Geo Pocket (Color)
- WonderSwan
- GameBoy (Color)
- GameBoy Advance
- Nintendo Entertainment System
- Super Nintendo Entertainment
- System/Super Famicom
- Virtual Boy
- PC Engine/TurboGrafx 16 (CD)
- SuperGrafx
- PC-FX
- Sega Game Gear
- Sega Genesis/Megadrive
- Sega Master System
- Sony PlayStation - (buggy, alpha state)

Answer (score 0):

Would one of these work?

$ apt-cache search gameboy | grep emulator
bsnes - Accurate SNES/SuperFamicom emulator
gngb - a Color Gameboy emulator
mednafen - multi-platform emulator, including NES, GB/A, Lynx, PC Engine

Answer (score 0):

Check some GBA Emulators here on [Romspedia](https://www.romspedia.com/emulators/gameboy-advance) and find the one that is the best for ubuntu system.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1179256)